# New install, re-indexed Amazon S3 folders, Craft not creating/finding transforms

Tags: assets, image-transforms, plugin-imageoptimize, amazon

Yesterday I re-indexed the contents of my image library on Amazon S3 to a fresh install.

I can see the images in Assets, I can use the images in entries and then tags/templates, I can import entries which find the images and I can create in-template transforms.

However, I cannot seem to get image transforms created - either in ImageOptimize, which I had used on my previous install, or just now testing with creating a Craft transform.

I tried forcing creation of one single asset via the command line, and got a timeout error:

`` php8.1: time limit exceeded `Operation canceled' @ fatal/cache.c/GetImagePixelCache/1877. ``

I am assuming that there's something between Craft and Amazon that's not 100% causing this, given that Craft too does not want to create native transforms?

(It is a long and boring story as to why I wasn't able to import the previous database, one which the Craft gang have been very helpful with!)